# Is it necessary to ask forgiveness from that person who has been told about zinah comitted by a person?

Tags: tawba, zina

If someone commits zinah and tells about it to someone else to get relieved from sorrow, is it necessary to ask forgiveness from the person with whom he or she shared the incident in case of istighfar for that sin? what is the best way to ask forgiveness for zinah?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information take our [tour] and check our [help]. Please clarify what you mean by jinah I think I've seen it quoted referring to sin is that correct? I don't know your cultural background, mine is Arabic.

Answer (score -1):

I am not any imam or anything, but with my knowledge is you gotta do two rakat and ask God for your wrongness sincerly by your heart you really have to feel sorry for that, and promise him not to do it again. And increase your daily prayer to show him you really do fear him and ask for forgiveness again and again.